# Why am I being asked to sign in on itunes on my computer?

Tags: ipad

I am suddenly being asked to sign into itunes on my computer before the download procedure can continue on my ipad...why is that?  It has never happened in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps to authenticate the content for use with the device? Perhaps provide some more detail on what exactly it is you're doing?